# Is there a function to join matching index pairs from two lists into a 2D list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm struggling to define what I mean in text so as an example:

```
>>> list_1 = ["text text text", "text more text", "also text", "so much text"]

>>> list_2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]

>>> list_combine = some_function(list_1, list_2)

>>> print(list_combine)
[["text text text", 0],
["text more text", 1],
["also text", 0],
["so much text", 1]]
```

Obviously one could simply perform a loop over range(len(one of the lists)) however I'm performing this on lists with several thousand items and wondered if there was a preexisting function that did this in a quicker way? I assume Numpy likely holds the answer but I'm unsure on the search terms to find it if it does exist.

Comment: Disagree with with marking this as a duplicate. That question clearly asks for tuples, I didn't. Not to mention "joining" could mean a myriad of things and the question title does not have any refining specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in function `zip()` does what you want. It produces tuples instead of lists, and you have to actually cast the resulting object to a `list` to get the desired output, but:

```
>>> list_1 = ["text text text", "text more text", "also text", "so much text"]
>>> list_2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> combined = list(zip(list_1, list_2))
>>> print(combined)
[('text text text', 0), 
 ('text more text', 1), 
 ('also text', 0), 
 ('so much text', 1)]
```

You could also use a list comprehension to get sublists by casting the tuples, if you really need lists instead of tuples, but that would end up being somewhat slower overall:

```
combined = [list(tup) for tup in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Note that `zip()` will truncate at the smallest iterable you feed it. If you want to zip bigger iterables, you can use `itertools.zip_longest()`.

Comment: Thank you!! That's perfect. Love some good list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to `.zip()` the lists together, and `for` loop through them, appending on each iteration.

```py
list_1 = ["text text text", "text more text", "also text", "so much text"]

list_2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]
list_combine = []
for f, b in zip(list_1, list_2):
    list_combine.append((f, b))

print(list_combine)
```

[See code snippet here](https://ideone.com/2WlCCU)

Comment: Solid answer though @Green Cloak Guy's compacted list comprehension is a little tidier I think. Personal preference of course.